# Cisco Packet tracer not logging in on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, cisco

I installed Cisco packet tracer on ubuntu 18.04 using [this link.](https://linuxhint.com/install_packet_tracer_ubuntu_1804/)
It works perfectly fine on "Guest session" but does not login to my cisco account. It throws this error whenever I try to login and asks to force quit:

```
./libcrypto.so.1.0.0: no version information available (required by ./PacketTracer7)
Floating point exception (core dumped)
```

Answer (score 2):

**For users who dual boot Windows**, I was able to login after symlink-ing the Windows fonts to `/usr/share/fonts`. In my case, I did the below:

```
ln -s /media/bjorn/Windows/Windows/Fonts /usr/share/fonts/windowsfonts
```

And to re-cache the fonts:

```
fc-cache
```

Before this, I did try `sudo apt install ttf-mscorefonts-installer` but it didn't work and perhaps packet tracer is using some extra fonts not included by `ttf-mscorefonts-installer`. So I have to resort to the solution above.

I found out about this from the [arch linux forums](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=252313), which involved installing `ttf-ms-fonts`. That package is for Arch Linux however, for Ubuntu it is `ttf-mscorefonts-installer` (which didn't work for me).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue trying to run it on Linux Mint. When running as sudo Packet Tracer would not automatically open the web window in order to login.

Running it without sudo solved the issue for me.

Tested it multiple times and it's the only solution I have